# Who first introduced the functional definition of symmetry?

Tags: ho.history-overview, definitions, symmetry

Who first introduced the definition of symmetry using functions explicitly? (That is, for instance, a *symmetry* of a subset $X$ of the plane is a *function* $F$ from the plane to the plane that preserves distance and $F(X) = X$).

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the essential idea---that symmetries have to do with invariance under certain reflections or rotations---go back to the ancients? Although they didn't have our function concept, they did understand all the isometries of the plane.

Comment: Well, to be more precise, I would like to know the first published book or article where symmetry in Geometry is defined as a function ... Thanks.

Comment: This would be a good question for the new hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The reference I posted in my answer seems to refute my comment above: evidently, the ancients did not use the concept of symmetry that way.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand correctly, you mean the definition of an object’s **{symmetries}** as its stabilizer under some group action on an ambient space. While a clearcut “first” might not exist, I’d say **Jordan** has early approximations to that, provided you are willing to replace “function” by “transformation”, “substitution”, or “motion”. E.g. in his [*Traité des substitutions* (1870, p. 50)](https://archive.org/stream/traitdessubsti00jorduoft#page/50):

> **§V. — Symmetry of rational functions.**
>
> *The link between groups and functions.*
>
> 60. Let $\mathrm F_1$ be an arbitrary rational function of $k$ letters $a, b, c,\dots$; $\mathrm F_1, \mathrm F_\alpha, \mathrm F_\beta$ the $1.2.\dots k$ functions obtained by letting the $1.2.\dots k$ substitutions $1, \alpha, \beta,\dots$ operate on these letters (...) The $M$ substitutions $1,\alpha,\dots$ which don’t alter the function $\mathrm F_1$ obviously form a group, which one can call the *function’s group*.

(Earlier Serret’s [*Cours d’algèbre supérieure* (1866, p. 387)](//archive.org/details/coursdalgbresup11serrgoog/page/n405) wrote that the “substitutions admises” by a function form a “système conjugué” ($=$ Cauchy’s term for *group*, p. 251). I’d have thought crystallographic groups were defined as stabilizers before this, but [it seems not](http://www.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/wallpaper/history.html).)

---

**EDIT:** To answer the question as recast in your comment (“first published book or article where symmetries ***in geometry*** are defined as transformations”), I think a problem is that early sources won’t call any maps *symmetries*: instead you’ll find expressions like *mouvements qui superposent à lui-même* ([Jordan 1867, p. 230](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3022r/f231)), *Transformationen in sich* ([Klein & Lie 1871](https://archive.org/stream/gesammeltemath01kleirich#page/n441); [Klein 1893, p. 326](https://archive.org/stream/eininhohere01kleirich#page/n9)), *Deckbewegungen* ([Sohncke 1875](https://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?08.0634.01), [p. 115](https://books.google.com/books?id=mYE7AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA113&dq=Deckbewegung)), *Deckoperationen* ([Schoenflies 1891, p. 13](https://books.google.com/books?id=HWlUAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA13); [Curie 1894, p. 395](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=umn.319510006112153&num=393); [Love 1906, p. 147](https://archive.org/stream/treatiseonmathem00loveuoft#page/147)), or at best *symmetry-operations* ([Hilton 1903, p. 32](https://archive.org/stream/mathematicalcry02hiltgoog#page/n48)).

While these references all contain the main idea, the exact terminology you want does not seem to appear until **A. Speiser**, [*Die Theorie der Gruppen von endlicher Ordnung* (2nd ed., 1927, p. 78)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-38551-7_7):

> Eine kongruente Abbildung des Gitters auf sich selber nennen wir eine ***Symmetrie*** des Gitters.

Interestingly, this sentence is absent in the first edition [(1923, p. 53)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-42031-7_6). In English, the earliest such definition I can find is by H. S. M. Coxeter in [*Regular skew polyhedra in three and four dimensions and their topological analogues* (1937, p. 35)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-43.1.33):

> We define a ***symmetry*** (or "symmetry operation") of any figure as a congruent transformation of the figure into itself (i.e., a combination of translations, rotations, and reflections).

Coxeter later repeats it in e.g. [*Mathematical Recreations and Essays* (1939, p. 130)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1940-07170-8) or [*Regular complex polytopes* (1974, p. 2)](https://books.google.com/books?id=9BY9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA2).

Comment: Thanks Ziegler. And what about euclidean geometry? Indeed, being more precise, I would like to know the first published book or article where symmetries (in Geometry) are defined as transformations.

Comment: You might check: Rogers, A. F. (1926). [**A mathematical study of crystal symmetry**](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20026154). Proceedings of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences (pp. 161-203). American Academy of Arts and Sciences. (In particular, "Symmetry Operations" beginning on p. 162 and the references contained therein.)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Why? I don't notice anything in Rogers that's not already in the above-quoted Hilton (1903)...

Comment: I had wondered specifically if there was anything of value in foot-note 3 of p. 163: The source is in German (Wulff, 1897) but I could not track down that particular reference... You are right that it (and other sources) are mentioned in Hilton (1903); I had not searched through Hilton for that reference, though it makes sense reading Rogers' acknowledgement at the end of the paper. (In any event: your answer here is very nice!)

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Thanks. I found the Wulff paper [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=SVIPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA556) -- I may be wrong but I'm not finding more about the OP's question in it.

Answer (score 8):

From the introduction of [Legendre's Revolution (1794): The Definition of Symmetry in Solid Geometry](http://www.jstor.org/stable/41134198), Giora Hon and Bernard R. Goldstein,
Archive for History of Exact Sciences, Vol. 59, No. 2 (January 2005), pp. 107-155.

> > The modern scientific concept of symmetry is, in the first place, a mathematical
> >     idea. It refers to an intrinsic property of a mathematical object which makes that object
> >     invariant under certain classes of transformations, such as rotation, reflection, inversion, or other operations. These invariant properties are the subject of group theory - a mathematical theory which explores, systématises and formalises these permanent features
> >     that are preserved by the object despite the transformation that it undergoes. The pervasiveness
> >     of symmetry in modern mathematics and science is well known, and it will be
> >     taken for granted here.
> >
> > In antiquity the fundamental meaning of summetrian Greek was proportion which
> >     in mathematics also meant commensurability. Clearly, the meaning of symmetry (Latin:
> >     symmetrid) changed over time, and it will be the goal of this paper to describe the introduction
> >     of this term into solid geometry at the end of the 18th century with an entirely
> >     new meaning. We put aside for another occasion the aesthetic sense of summetria/symmetria
> >     in antiquity as well-proportioned (notably in Vitruvius's De architecture^ and
> >     its subsequent applications in architecture and art (and, to some extent, in scientific
> >     contexts).
> >
> > In fact, in the period from 1794 to 1815 three scientists claimed to use symmetry in
> >     a new way: Adrien-Marie Legendre (1752-1833) in solid geometry (1794), Sylvestre
> >     François Lacroix (1765-1843) in algebra (1797), and René- Just Haüy (1743-1822) in
> >     crystallography (1815). In a series of papers now in preparation we will discuss the introduction
> >     of symmetry in algebra and in crystallography, and then argue that **the modern
> >     usages of symmetry in all scientific domains flow from these three seminal figures.**
> >
> > ...
> >
> > In this paper we investigate Legendre's work on solid geometry where he introduced
> >     a new definition of symmetry that, we claim, has served as the basis for the modern
> >     scientific concept of symmetry.

This text seems to be an extremely thorough account of the history of the modern concept of symmetry.

Comment: Hon and Goldstein have expanded their thesis into a [book](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-8448-5) which has interesting reviews ([one](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2724356), [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2008.10.002)): there «their argument that Legendre, the “hero” of their saga, (1) gave a “definition” of “symmetry” which was at once (2) a drastic break with the past and (3) a seminal influence on the future» is hotly contested on all 3 counts.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks for those reviews, which are indeed interesting. It seems the history of this concept is slippery; I'm inclined to agree with a remark mentioned in one of the reviews, that symmetry is a concept without a history, because it is innate.

Comment: Other reviews, to which I don't seem to have access, may be more positive: ([three](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1525/jsah.2009.68.4.576), [four](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1600-0498.2010.00171.x), [five](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/book-reviews/58109928/from-summetria-symmetry-making-revolutionary-scientific-concept), [six](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/book-reviews/52926633/mathematical-aesthetic-aspects-symmetry))...